# Sum of two long long int when they give a result bigger thant long long int?

Tags: c, math, long-integer, integer-overflow

Is there a possible way to sum two different `long long int` variables when the result is going to be bigger than a `long long int` in C?

Comment: What result would you like to get from the sum?

Comment: ^^, you need a long long long int

Comment: I'd like the program to print the result in the screen, I'm expecting a bigger number than the one long long int can hold.

Comment: have you tried with big integer solution?

Comment: use `int128_t` if possible.

Comment: @Daedra I can point you to https://gmplib.org/ library, for example. You can then provide working sample as the answer to this question.

Comment: if you're on a 64-bit platform, use [`int128_t`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) if that's feasible. Otherwise you need a [tag:bigint] library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or [Boost::Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multiprecision/)

Comment: If you don't have 128-bit ints and don't want to use external libraries, convert both numbers to digit arrays and sum these, with a possible carry.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll check them all and provide an answer with a solution that fits my requirements better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP wants to "print the result in the screen", divide the number in 2 parts: Most-Significant-Digits and Least-Significant-Digit.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_long_long_sum(long long a, long long b) {
  if ((a < 0) == (b < 0)) {  // a and b of the same sign?
    // Sum the Most-Significatn_Digits and Least-Significant Digit separately
    int sumLSD = (int) (a % 10 + b % 10);
    long long sumMSDs = a / 10 + b / 10 + sumLSD / 10;
    sumLSD %= 10;
    printf("sum = ");
    if (sumMSDs) {
      printf("%lld", sumMSDs);
      // Since sign already printed, insure next print is positive
      sumLSD = abs(sumLSD); 
    }
    printf("%d\n", sumLSD);
  } else { // No need to separate as there is no chance for overflow
    printf("sum = %lld\n", a + b);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a grat approach on how to solve it, with your method I was able to get 9223372036854775805676 wich is insanely big. Thank you very much, you gave me a good idea.

Comment: @Daedra Note: I did not use the separate parts when the sign differs.  Had code done so, then `sumLSD` and `sumMSDs` could be of different signs and that unduly complicates the math and print.